# How to animate changing text in paragraph?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, text, css-animations

I have component which shows text message in `<p></p>` **according to specific condition**:

```
const StatusBar = ({ currentPlayer }) => {
    return (
        <div className="status-bar-container">
            <p>
                {currentPlayer?.color === Colors.BLACK
                    ? "⚫️ Black player's turn"
                    : "⚪️ White player's turn"}
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Is it possible to **animate transition** between first (*'Black player's turn'*) and second (*'White player's turn'*) messages using *CSS/SCSS* or some react animation libs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not come up with an idea how to animate it properly in this configuration but I've made a **small change** and now I am pretty ok with what's happening on screen:

```
const StatusBar = ({ currentPlayer }) => {
    return (
        <div className="status-bar-container">
            {currentPlayer?.color === Colors.BLACK ? (
                <p>⚫️ Black player's turn</p>
            ) : (
                <p>⚪️ White player's turn</p>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

If you make it this way `React` will only rerender the **difference** between `⚫️ Black player's turn` and `⚪️ White player's turn` which is only the first part (`⚫️ Black` and `⚪️ White`).

This looks much **smoother** than rendering the whole message all over again.